# How to save item of FlatList in AsyncStorage react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have a Flatlist that the data loaded from state. what i wan to do this when i click to a heart Icon that item addToWishlist using AsynStorage

i dont have any idea in my AddToWishList() function
can anyone please help??

Comment: I added a generic solution but can better tailor it if you shared your state. Also, do you need to save the entire object, or just id to use for reference later?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the entire item object, AddToWishList should pass back the id from where it's being called.

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

AddToWishList = async (id) => {
  let itemToSave = JSON.Stringify(...dataArrayOfItems.filter(item => item.id === id))
  try {
   await AsyncStorage.setItem(id: itemToSave) 
    }
   catch (error) {
        //error saving data
    }
}
```